# How to add new dataframe column from json type series(string)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to parse and process my dataframe data.

I tried using join, assign ... etc.
I succeed parsing 'allowed' column with below code:

```
allowed_expanded = df1.allowed.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
allowed_expanded.columns = ['{}.{}'.format('allowed',i) for i in allowed_expanded]
```

and the result:

```
# allowed_expanded

                                             allowed.0                  allowed.1   allowed.2
0           {'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}                        NaN         NaN
1   {'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}                    NaN         NaN
2                               {'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}     {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}         NaN
3                            {'IPProtocol': 'all'}                        NaN         NaN
```

but this is not what I want.

what should do I do ?

now my data looks:

```
# print(df)
          network                                            allowed
0           vpc-1           [{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}]
1           vpc-1   [{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}]
2           vpc-1   [{'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}, {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}]
3           vpc-1                            [{'IPProtocol': 'all'}]
...
```

and...
what I want:

```
# print(df)
          network           allowed.IPProtocol    allowed.ports
0           vpc-1                          tcp               53
1           vpc-1                          tcp         22, 3389
2           vpc-1                   icmp, sctp                -
3           vpc-1                          all                -
...
```

Comment: can you provide your example(`df`) to code? you can use `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: @Panda Kim, the result of `df.head().to_dict()` is the below.

`{'network': {0: 'vpc-1',
  1: 'vpc-1',
  2: 'vpc-1',
  3: 'vpc-1'},
 'allowed': {0: "[{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}]",
  1: "[{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}]",
  2: "[{'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}, {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}]",
  3: "[{'IPProtocol': 'all'}]"
  }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(row):
    IPProtocol = []
    ports = []
    for item in row:
        IPProtocol.append(item.get('IPProtocol', None))
        ports.append(item.get('ports', None))
    return pd.Series([IPProtocol, ports])

df[['allowed.IPProtocol', 'allowed.ports']] = df['allowed'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I tried but I got the error messages the below.
`----> 5 for item in row:
      6     IPProtocol.append(item.get('IPProtocol', None))
      7     ports.append(item.get('ports', None))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: Can you share the output of `type(df.allowed.iloc[0])`?

Comment: the output of `type(df.allowed.iloc[0])` is `list`

Comment: It seems to work on the system (for the rows you shared). I'm confused about how the `float` is popping up. Can you check the type of `row` in the `func` and assert if it is a `float`? Looks like some row in the `df` isn't `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
import numpy as np

df['allowed.IPProtocol']=df['allowed'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i['IPProtocol'] for i in x] if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan))
df['allowed.ports']=df['allowed'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([', '.join(i['ports']) if 'ports' in list(i.keys()) else 'nan' for i in x] if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan))
```

**Output**:

```
|    | network   | allowed                                          | allowed.IPProtocol   | allowed.ports   |
|---:|:----------|:-------------------------------------------------|:---------------------|:----------------|
|  0 | vpc-1     | [{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}]         | tcp                  | 53              |
|  1 | vpc-1     | [{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}] | tcp                  | 22, 3389        |
|  2 | vpc-1     | [{'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}, {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}] | icmp, sctp           | nan, nan        |
|  3 | vpc-1     | [{'IPProtocol': 'all'}]                          | all                  | nan             |
```

Comment: I tried, but I got the error below..

`----> 4 df['allowed.IPProtocol']=df['allowed'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i['IPProtocol'] for i in x]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: It seems there are nan values in the dataset. Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'network': {0: 'vpc-1',   1: 'vpc-1',   2: 'vpc-1',   3: 'vpc-1'},  'allowed': {0: "[{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}]",   1: "[{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}]",   2: "[{'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}, {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}]",   3: "[{'IPProtocol': 'all'}]"   }}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    network allowed
0   vpc-1   [{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}]
1   vpc-1   [{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}]
2   vpc-1   [{'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}, {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}]
3   vpc-1   [{'IPProtocol': 'all'}]
```

**Step1**

eval and explode and so on..

```
df1 = df['allowed'].apply(eval).explode().apply(pd.Series).explode('ports')
```

`df1`

```
    IPProtocol  ports
0   tcp         53
1   tcp         22
1   tcp         3389
2   icmp        NaN
2   sctp        NaN
3   all         NaN
```

**Step2**

`groupby` df1 by index

```
df2 = df1.fillna('-').groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))
```

`df2`

```
    IPProtocol  ports
0   tcp         53
1   tcp         22,3389
2   icmp,sctp   -
3   all         -
```

`join` df and df2

```
out = df[['network']].join(df2.add_prefix('allowed.'))
```

`out`

```
    network allowed.IPProtocol  allowed.ports
0   vpc-1   tcp                 53
1   vpc-1   tcp                 22,3389
2   vpc-1   icmp,sctp           -
3   vpc-1   all                 -
```

Comment: This code works for me. Thank you so much. But I have another problem,
When 'allowed' column has a NaN, this code doesn't work... 

data like this:
`'allowed': {0: "[{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['53']}]",   1: "[{'IPProtocol': 'tcp', 'ports': ['22', '3389']}]",   2: "[{'IPProtocol': 'icmp'}, {'IPProtocol': 'sctp'}]",   3: "[{'IPProtocol': 'all'}]",   4: nan}`

Comment: I tried the below code:
`df1 = df9["allowed"].apply(lambda x: x.apply(eval).explode().apply(pd.Series).explode('ports') if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan)`

But I got this error message..
'str' object has no attribute 'apply'